# Как правильно расставить запятые в предложении?

Tags: однородные-члены, запятые, придаточное-предложение

"По вечерам ты всё же мониторишь HeadHunter, ищешь(,) что посолиднее(,) и чтобы перспективы обещали".

Мне кажется, первая запятая ставится, т.к. пропущено слово "то". Вторая запятая не ставится, ибо идёт параллельное подчинение придаточных. Верно?

Но что делать в этом случае.
"По вечерам ты всё же мониторишь HeadHunter, ищешь что-нибудь посолиднее(,) и чтобы перспективы обещали".

Здесь ставится запятая? Тоже наблюдается параллельное подчинение. Ищешь что? "Что-нибудь посолиднее" и "чтобы перспективы обещали". Однако первое — дополнение, второе — придаточное предложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) По вечерам ты всё же мониторишь HeadHunter, **ищешь, что посолиднее и чтобы перспективы обещали.**

Это однородные изъяснительные придаточные, одиночный союз И.

2) По вечерам ты всё же мониторишь HeadHunter, **ищешь что-нибудь посолиднее и чтобы перспективы обещали.**

Здесь однородные отношения между членом предложения (дополнением) и придаточным предложением.

Comment: Вот что нашёл:
Не следует соединять как однородные члены разнотипные синтаксические конструкции:
член предложения и придаточное предложение:
"Я не люблю войну и когда получаю двойку"
(http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/784-34_predlozheniya_s_odnorodnymi_chlenami.html)
Ваш первый пример не противоречит правилу, но вот второй...

Comment: А Пушкин соединял, и Достоевский тоже. Я думал уж о форме плана и как героя назову.На мгновение чуть не позабыли Настасью Филипповну и что всё-таки она хозяйка своего вечера. А вот современная разговорная речь: Приезжай завтра или когда тебе будет удобно.